# jQuery validator validates falsely - one of two fields required

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a form where I want to require either the phone number of the visitor or an email address.
I want to require this, while the form is an information request form and I want to make sure I have at least one feedback channel - giving the user the choice which one to use *(or both perhaps)*.

I'm struck here since a while and couldn't find appropriate information in other, quite similar questions - somehow it all didn't fit. Please forgive me therefore a duplicate question; I just cannot see where I error.
Here is my almost complete form *(only stripped out what I found good and also unnecessary for the question)*:

```
  <div class="propertydetailrequest form-group">
    <input type="text" name="cntnt01fbrp__31" value="" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Your Name *" id="fbrp__31" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" name="cntnt01fbrp__58[]" value="" class="form-control require-one" placeholder="Your Email" id="fbrp__58_1" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="cntnt01fbrp__33" value="" class="form-control require-one" placeholder="Your Telephone" id="fbrp__33" />
  </div>
  <div class="required">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="cntnt01fbrp__56" value="t" required="required" id="fbrp__56" />
    <label for="fbrp__56">I read and have accepted the <a href="gdpr.html">privacy policy</a> <span class="red">*</span></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <script>
// adding script here within the form instead of in a global script file
// using vanilla JS to enable jQuery after it has been loaded before </body>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").addClass('disabled');
  $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', true);

  $.getScript("http://example.com/assets/js/validate.min.js", function () {
    $( "#cntnt01moduleform_1" ).validate({
      errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
        return true; // just hiding that error message
      },
      rules: {
        fbrp__58_1: {
          require_from_group: [1, ".require-one"],
          email: true // does validate email addresses and empty is fine too
        },
        fbrp__33: {
          require_from_group: [1, ".require-one"]
        }
      }
    }); // eof validate
  });  //eof getscript

// trying to make sending the form without validation impossible
  $('#cntnt01moduleform_1 input').on('keyup blur', function () {
    if ($('#cntnt01moduleform_1').valid()) {
      console.log('validated onBlur'); // make sure the plugin validates and not the browser
      $('input#cntnt01fbrp_submit').removeClass('disabled'); $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('input#cntnt01fbrp_submit').addClass('disabled'); $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
  $('#fbrp__56').change(function() {
    if ($('#cntnt01moduleform_1').valid()) {
      console.log('validated onClick'); // make sure the plugin validates and not the browser
      $('input#cntnt01fbrp_submit').removeClass('disabled'); $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('input#cntnt01fbrp_submit').addClass('disabled'); $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });

});  // eof dom load
</script> 
  </div>
  <div class="submit text-right">
    <input class="btn btn-success" name="cntnt01fbrp_submit" id="cntnt01fbrp_submit" value="Senden" type="submit"  />
  </div>
</form>
```

However, the form is valid after giving only the name *(required by HTML attribute)* and checking the GDPR checkbox on *(this also is required by HTML)*. Apparently the validator plugin does validate the form - even though I ask it in the options to make one of them required.
The console logs are to be erased later - I'm just trying to figure which event fires when with this.

Comment: Regarding your section called *"trying to make sending the form without validation impossible"* ~ It's JavaScript... the user simply disables JavaScript and he can do whatever he wants.  Secondly, why are you manually adding and removing classes with your own `keyup` and `blur` handlers?  That is literally the point of the validation plugin, besides blocking submit.

Comment: Update *after* my question was answered, just for clarification: I merged the _jquery.validate.min.js_ and the _additional-methods.min.js_ into one file for network speed. I do need them both anyway, so I combined them to save unnecessary roundtrips.

Comment: @Sparky The page is stuffed with JavaScript anyway. In the next step I'm working on the fallbacks, like if <body class="noscript"> persists. So I see this only as a way to support the user with his interaction and secure valid submissions not out of intention but actually the unintended ones.
The classes only give additional visual feedback and are from the Bootstrap framework I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all the required jquery plugins. Therefore you must also include the   [additional methods library](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validate)

Also, as far as I know the rule names should reference the names (and not the id) of the inputs, therefore don't use `fbrp__58_1` and `fbrp__33`, rather `cntnt01fbrp__58` and `cntnt01fbrp__33`, respectively

Therefore:

```
   <form id="cntnt01moduleform_1">
        <div class="propertydetailrequest form-group">
            <input type="text" name="cntnt01fbrp__31" value="" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Your Name *" id="fbrp__31" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" name="cntnt01fbrp__58" value="" class="form-control require-one" placeholder="Your Email" id="fbrp__58_1" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="cntnt01fbrp__33" value="" class="form-control require-one" placeholder="Your Telephone" id="fbrp__33" />
        </div>com
        <div class="required">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="cntnt01fbrp__56" value="t" required="required" id="fbrp__56" />
          <label for="fbrp__56">I read and have accepted the <a href="gdpr.html">privacy policy</a> <span class="red">*</span></label>
        </div>

        <div>
        <script>
            // adding script here within the form instead of in a global script file
            // using vanilla JS to enable jQuery after it has been loaded before </body>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

          $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").addClass('disabled');
          $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', true);


            $( "#cntnt01moduleform_1" ).validate({
              errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
                return true; // just hiding that error message
              },
              rules: {
                cntnt01fbrp__58: {
                  require_from_group: [1, ".require-one"],
                  minlength: 2 //I just added this. You can remove it if you want to
                  //email: true // does validate email addresses and empty is fine too
                },
                cntnt01fbrp__33: {
                  require_from_group: [1, ".require-one"],
                  minlength: 2 //I just added this. You can remove it if you want tp
                }
              } 
            }); // eof validate



        // trying to make sending the form without validation impossible
          $('#cntnt01moduleform_1 input').on('keyup blur', function () {

            if ($('#cntnt01moduleform_1').valid()) {

              console.log('validated onBlur'); // make sure the plugin validates and not the browser
              $('input#cntnt01fbrp_submit').removeClass('disabled'); $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                console.log('validation failed')
              $('input#cntnt01fbrp_submit').addClass('disabled'); $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', true);
            }
          });
          $('#fbrp__56').change(function() {
            if ($('#cntnt01moduleform_1').valid()) {
              console.log('validated onClick'); // make sure the plugin validates and not the browser
              $('input#cntnt01fbrp_submit').removeClass('disabled'); $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
              $('input#cntnt01fbrp_submit').addClass('disabled'); $("#cntnt01fbrp_submit").prop('disabled', true);
            }
          });

        });  // eof dom load
    </script> 
  </div>
  <div class="submit text-right">
    <input class="btn btn-success" name="cntnt01fbrp_submit" id="cntnt01fbrp_submit" value="Senden" type="submit"  />
  </div>
</form>
```

Add this to your file just before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.js" integrity="sha256-xLhce0FUawd11QSwrvXSwST0oHhOolNoH9cUXAcsIAg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.min.js" integrity="sha256-vb+6VObiUIaoRuSusdLRWtXs/ewuz62LgVXg2f1ZXGo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome - exactly the names were the issue. Thank you very much for your help!
Honestly, I only read the quick tutorial at https://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/ 
However, here are IDs and Names exactly same spelled. So, without digging into the documentation, one could run into this just like I did.
Again, thank you very much; seeing it from here it was a stupid question... ^^